# How to do Windows phone developer Registration (Developer Unlock)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I connected the windows phone with system. Zune player is lunched. After that open the  Windows phone developer Registration form and given the ID and Password, it showed the msg successfully registered.But again i open the Windows phone developer Registration Form it asking for registration. how to solve the problem.?

Comment: Do you see your device on AppHub? Visual Studio throws an error during deployment in debug mode?

Comment: Yes
Visual Studio throws an error :
Error 1 Failed to connect to device as it is developer locked. For details on developer unlock, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195284

Comment: On https://users.create.msdn.com/Account/Profile, do you see your device??

Comment: I'm not suggesting this is off-topic here, but you might be interested in [windowsphone.se].

Answer (score 0):

Check on the apphub (https://users.create.msdn.com/Account/Profile Devices tab) to see if the device is listed as unlocked or not.

What is the exact message you receive after unlocking and the Status message shown when you connect a device?

**Update Dec 2015**
The location of the list of unlocked WP8 devices is now at https://dev.windows.com/en-us/Account/DeviceManagement

Comment: No message was shown after unlocked when the phone was connected to phone. the problem was when

Comment: @Jegadeesh why do you think it was successful if there was no confirmation message shown?